# looping through a dataframe

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a dataframe with 57 columns and 122 rows. For each column, I want to calculate two things:

1) Number of values less than -1

(2) Number of time value less than -1 appear consecutively three times or more. For e.g. if the data is:

```
dat<-c(1,-1,-1.3,-1.2,-1,0.5,3.2,2.2,-1,-1,0,-4,-3,-2,-1,2)
```

For part (1) of the question, I did this:

```
bd<-sum(dat< -1)
>5
```

For part (2) it was complicated:

```
tmpdat<-data.frame(values=dat, tmp_vals=dat)
tmpdat$tmp_vals[tmpdat$values<(-1)]<-"lower"
bds<-data.frame(Values=rle(tmpdat$tmp_vals)$values,Sequential=rle(tmpdat$tmp_vals)$lengths)
sum(bds$Sequential >= 3 & bds$Values == "lower")
>1
```

I want to create a loop to do this for each column of my data frame. This is what the loop looks like for (1):

```
for (i in 1:ncol(d.f)){
        d.f[i]<-sum(d.f.[i]< -1)
```

}

I want to create within this loop for the second part but do not know how to do it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: the provided data is numeric vector not a data frame. Solutions may vary for data frames and vector.

Comment: If you have  a data.frame as you mentioned `colSums(df1< -1)`  For the second case, `lapply(df1, function(x) {rl <- rle(x < -1); sum(rl$lengths[rl$values]>=3)})`

Comment: @DavidArenburg You could post that as a solution.  I don't mind :-)

Comment: @akrun, no, you handled the whole thing pretty much

Comment: Thanks both of you. The code works great! Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question, it may be easier to use `colSums`.  We get a logical matrix with `df1 < -1` and `sum` the `TRUE` values in the matrix with `colSums`

```
 colSums(df1< -1, na.rm=TRUE)
```

`na.rm=TRUE` can be used as an optional argument in case there are some missing values (`NA`).

We can loop (`vapply`) through the columns of the dataset ('df1') and apply `rle` (modified from @David Arenburg's comments)

```
  vapply(df1, function(x) 
          sum(with(rle(x < -1), lengths[values]) > 2), numeric(1))
```

For looping through the columns, we can also use `lapply/sapply`.  Here, I used `vapply` as it may be a bit more faster and also it is safer (in case there are non-numeric elements, it should give error).   In each column, we get the `rle` of `x <-1` i.e. `TRUE, FALSE` run-lengths and subset the `lengths` corresponding to TRUE values (`lengths[values]`), check whether it is greater than 2 (`>2`) and get the `sum`.